# Turn off iCloud Music library on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

I have recently got rid of my Apple Music subscription (and moved to Spotify), as part of my sub I used to use iCloud Music Library. Now with Apple Music gone I want to just sync my library the old way using iTunes however I am shown this screen:

[image]

There is no option in Settings > Music to turn off my iCloud Music library on my phone. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was solved by Apple Support. I signed out of Apple ID in Settings > iCloud and signed back in again.

Answer (score 1):

On your phone, navigate to Settings > Music.  There you will see "Show Apple Music" and "Sync Library".  Make sure both of those are off.  I believe that you will not see iCloud Music Library any longer.

Comment: Both are already off.

Comment: Which version of iOS are you using?  My answer assumes a fully updated phone (ie iOS 13): I think that the menu options changed between when I used iCloud music to now

Comment: I’m using iOS13.2

Comment: I don't know why anyone upvoted me.  I didn't solve the OP's question